# LISTA_DE_BOTONES programa en java

Tags: java

`introducir el código aquí`[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buen dia, me gustaria saber como puedo hacer un codigo que:
al abrir una ventana, en la ventana me muestre una lista de botones, pero cada boton posee diferente informacion, [una imagen, descripcion, precio], como mostrarlo sin tener que declararlo . son productos.
pero no puedo usar librerias dinamicas [arrayList,...] la informacion la tengo almacenda en una lista circular simple, lo que no se es como hacer los botones??

ayuda por favor [para java]
, buen dia

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
public class Tabla {
    public void ver_tablav3(JTable tabla) {
        try {
            NodoProducto actual = ListaProducto.getInstancia().getPrimero().getSiguiente();
            Object matriz[][] = new Object[ListaProducto.getInstancia().getTamanio()][4];
            tabla.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new Render());
            JButton btn2 = new JButton("AÑADIR"); 
            btn2.setSize(40, 40);
            btn2.setName("e");
         
            if (ListaProducto.getInstancia().getPrimero() != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < ListaProducto.getInstancia().getTamanio(); i++) {

                    matriz[i][0] = urll(actual.getP().getDirImg());
                    matriz[i][1] = actual.getP().getDescripcion();
                    matriz[i][2] = String.valueOf(actual.getP().getPrecio());
                    matriz[i][3] = btn2;
                    actual = actual.getSiguiente();
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("\t Lista Circular vacía.");
            }
            tabla.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
                    matriz, new String[]{"IMAGEN", "DESCRIPCION", "PRECIO", "COMPRAR"}
            ) {
                @Override
                public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                    return false;
                }

            });

            tabla.setRowHeight(70);
            tabla.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(tabla.getPreferredSize());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error hop " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public JLabel urll(String url) {
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        label.setSize(130, 70);
        ImageIcon lbl = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(url));
        Icon agre = new ImageIcon(lbl.getImage().getScaledInstance(label.getWidth(), label.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
        label.setIcon(agre);
        return label;
    }

}
```

[image: RESULTADO]

Comment: Hola, Alejandro. Bienvenido al sitio. Te serviría leer esto [https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask] para tener una mejor respuesta a tus preguntas. Java posee una serie de estructuras de datos que nos ayudan para almacenar y representar mejor la información. Mencionas que no puedes usar ArrayList, pero no dices el motivo. Serviría de mucho ver que llevas hecho para entender mejor el problema.

Comment: Gracia por responder, no puedo usar ArrayList y otras librerias dinamicas,si no son creadas por mi. [restricciones].este es el problema, estoy haciendo un progr que puede almacenar productos [en una lista circular simple] en sus atributos estan: nombre, precio,direc de img;  ya tengo la lista[puedo agregar, recorrer,eliminar..] pero estos productos los tengo que visualizar en una ventana. como en la imagen que subi.ahora mi pregunta es como puedo hacer un arreglo [o algo] que me nuestre digamos tengo 5 prod agregados al ir a la ventana que me visualize esos 5 productos??? gracias por responder

Comment: ¿Qué llevas escrito, qué has intentado hacer?   
Quizá estás confundiendo "librería dinámica" con librería externa o propietaria. Puedes usar ArrayList, List, etc. sin problema alguno.

Comment: Incluye el código de lo que has intentado para dar una solucón que se ajuste mejor a tu problema

Comment: Los siento gracias por responder, al final lo que hice fue colocarlos en una tabla, y hacer un recorrido con un ciclo. ahorita les muestro lo que hice.

Comment: Lo siento soy nuevo, no he dado el recorrido todavía, pero eso fue lo que hice, aun que la imagen todavía no lo he hecho.

Comment: Pero ahora tengo otro problema, tengo dos listas: la primera es una lista de productos almacenada en una [lista circular simple] y la segunda es una lista de ofertas almacenada en una [cola de prioridad] AHORA, lo que tengo que hacer es que las ofertas tengan una lista de productos pero al hacerlo no me cargan los productos... COMO SE PODRIA HACER , ???

Comment: No podemos hacer más si no muestras qué has hecho.  

En la imagen que colocaste se puede ver que tienes un objeto de tipo NodoProducto  llamado actual  y le asignas un valor de la lista ListaProducto. Se entiende que es el producto actual. Después creas una matriz con un no. de filas de ListaProducto y 4 columnas(Nombre, Descripcion, Precio, JButton). 

Ahora bien, ¿cuando compilas o ejecutas tu código te sale algún error o no se muestra lo que quieres?

Comment: Hola, mmm lo que he hecho es: hacer una tabla, en la tabla lleva JLabel, descripcion, precio, JButton, el boton me lo muestra, ahora con el JLabel  no me acepta [ahi lo que quiero es que conforme sea el ciclo del for el url cambie para agregarcelo al JLabel] pero no me lo carga solo me carga uno y no me acepta la matriz [i][0] ese objeto.....   
Solo si coloco una direccion si me corre el programa

Comment: arriba hay un ejemplo de como queda:

Comment: @Alejandro creo que primero deberías de hacer [el recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) si es que no lo has hecho, los snippets son únicamente para HTML, css y JS, no para Java

Comment: XD jajaja si me acabo de dar cuenta, espero que se entienda, gracias por la sugerencia